# What is the mistake in converting this sum into an integral? Why is the integral negative?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Suppose $0<B<A$ and I am looking at the summation
$$ S(N) = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{\Delta x}{A - k\Delta x} $$
where $A - N\Delta x = B$. The summand is of the form $\Delta x / x_{k}$ where $x_{0} = A$, $x_{1} = A-\Delta x$, $x_{2} = A-2\Delta x$, etc. Now when I send $N\rightarrow\infty$, I expect to get a Riemann integral out, so I expect
$$ \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} S(N) = \int_{A}^{B} \frac{dx}{x}. $$
However, when I make the evaluation, I get
$$ \int_{A}^{B} \frac{dx}{x} = \ln B - \ln A = \ln \left(\frac{B}{A}\right) < 0. $$
This is a negative number, because $B<A$. However, the summation is positive, so my simple question is, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Use Riemann sum definition properly. $$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(a+k\Delta x)$$

Comment: You should expect a negative answer because the integrand is positive and the upper limit is less than the lower limit, so you are integrating in the negative direction.

Comment: @RossMillikan I understand that part. My question lies in the subtlety of exactly how the integral arises from the summation. That's the part interesting to me, and the answer in the end shouldn't be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you've miscalculated $\Delta x.$ To obtain it, we take "upper" limit (in this case, $B$) minus "lower" limit (in this case, $A$), divided by $N.$ That means that $\Delta x$ is necessarily negative, and that $$B=A+N\Delta X.$$ Also, for any $0\leq k<N,$ we have $0<B<x_k:=A+k\Delta x,$ and so your summands $\frac{\Delta x}{x_k}$ are all negative.

The potentially confusing terminology is "upper" limit and "lower" limit. By this, we *don't* necessarily mean the greater of the two limits and the lesser. Rather, we indicate where those limits are written next to the integral sign (the upper end or lower end).

Comment: Oh wow. There were a couple of reply answers I expected to get, but this was not one of them! That's actually really subtle. Your answer is really nice.

Comment: It's definitely an easy mistake to make! I'm glad my answer cleared things up.